# Is it mandatory to specify intermediate model to describe 'level' of many-to-many relationship?

Tags: django, django-models, many-to-many

Being new to Django and relatively new to python, I am writing a knowledge reporting webpage.

I have 2 models with a defined MtM relationship:

```
Class Student:
level_of_knowledge = model.ManyToMany(Topic)
...

Class Topic:
...
```

**Intended usage**:
Every Student has a level of understanding of every topic (the list of topics is exactly the same for everyone), starting with, say, "`Basic`". The level of understanding may be increased to "`Intermediate`" and further to "`Advanced`".

**Question**: 
Is it necessary to implement an intermediate "through" model with the determined list of levels of undestanding, or can it be done in the `level_of_knowledge` field in `Student` model directly?

Comment: Question: Are you trying to say that EACH topic has its own "Level of Understanding"? e.g. A student knows "Calculus" to an "Intermediate" level, and that same student knows "Algebra" to an "Advanced" level?

Comment: @Hybrid yes, the topics will be organized in a non-intersecting way (i.e. no "Combinatorics" and "Discrete mathematics", as the former is a subset of latter)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally, I would create an intermediate model in this case, but if you want more ideas of what you could do then something like this would work too:

```
Class Student:
    advanced_knowledge = model.ManyToMany(Topic)
    intermediate_knowledge = model.ManyToMany(Topic)
    basic_knowledge = model.ManyToMany(Topic)
    ...

Class Topic:
    ...
```

So this is neat because you can easily access knowledge of a certain level by using `student.basic_knowledge.all()`

But here's the problem:

1. What if you want a list of all `Topic` objects related to a `Student`? Do you combine all three of these queries?
2. What if you want to add a few more knowledge levels? Maybe later students will have beginner knowledge or expert knowledge. How many other ManyToMany fields will you end up adding?

Using an intermediate model solves both of these problems, and its not hard to use the django `through` option and filter by levels if you want. Just make properties or methods on `Student` for the knowledge levels you filter by most often.

```
Class Student:
    level_of_knowledge = model.ManyToMany(Topic, through=MyIntermediteModel)

    def advanced_knowledge(self):
        return self.level_of_knowledge.filter(...) # filter by intermedite model where level = 'advanced'
```